# How can I draw one axis frequency distribution graph in d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, histogram

How can I draw a one axis frequency distribution graph in d3? The plot should take an array like [3 34 234 32 33 23] and draw a marker at every of the occurring elements on a one dimensional axis. The graph should look like this:
[image]

There are ways to plot histograms like this in d3:

```
// Generate a histogram using twenty uniformly-spaced bins.
var data = d3.layout.histogram()
    .bins(x.ticks(20))
    (values);
```

But how can I generate the one dimensional version of these?

Comment: question is not clear what do you mean one dimentional

Comment: thanks I added a data example. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: so isn't this like a barchart with all bars having same height? and bars at x =3, x=34 x=234 so on ... in reference data set you given .. [3 34 234 32 33 23] .It will be best if you can put a screen shot of how the graph will look as per the data you have given..

Comment: If yes then you can make a barchart like this http://plnkr.co/edit/434qFl0uZzM7BfMFnI3H?p=preview

Answer (score 6):

Here are two possible approaches, depending on what you want:

## Solution A

Just draw a semitransparent rectangle for each data point. Example: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/be1b4d11d420bcfc76a6a2005d0b2fe5

## Solution B

`var data = d3.layout.histogram().bins(x.ticks(20))(values);` just generates data, and not the chart. You can use that data to make a one-dimensional chart.

For example, if you're referring to Mike Bostock's example histogram at: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3048450, you can remove the frequency mapping to bar height, and map it to opacity instead. First you'd add a scale that maps frequency to opacity:

```
var opacity = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.y; })])
    .range([0, 1]);
```

and change the line that says:

```
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.y); });
```

to something like:

```
    .attr("height", 50)
    .style("opacity", function(d) { return opacity(d.y); });
```

You'd also want to reformat the height and spacing of the bars. You can see a sample here: http://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/d460f85cc770a7c63221d390d733c1f5

Alternatively you may want to map frequency to color, instead of opacity, in that case your scale would be a color scale, and you'd use "fill" instead of "opacity".